# Why should the trust anchor not be included in the PKIX certification path?

Tags: java, security, encryption, ssl, ssl-certificate

In the [PKIX documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html) it mentions:

> 1. The certificate representing the
>    TrustAnchor should not be included in
>    the certification path

My question is, where does this restriction come from? In the [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-73) I only found:

> 2. A certificate MUST NOT appear more
>    than once in a prospective
>    certification path.

Does the statement (2) in RFC somehow imply statement (1)? Because I can not see it.

What problem would be created by having the trust anchor in the path as well?
In the end, the TA certificate can validate itself.

Could anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more a definitional thing, IIUC.  A valid certification path is defined in RFC 5280 and one condition is that its first certificate is signed by a trust anchor (and that the issuerName of the certificate matches that trust anchor's name).  (Trust anchors need not be certificates.)

Comment: You are right.A TA object in java can be initialized with the public key and the name.But if there is the actual TA certificate first in the path (as per 5280) I can not see the problem.It will still use its own key for validation.The reason I am asking this, is because in a specific case using the PKIX apis I happened to have the TA certificate as the first and only certificate in the validation path and also happened to have the same certificate passed as pararmeter of TrustAnchor.I got exception "Could not find valid path".But the certificate were the same!I am lost at this point

Comment: My guess is that it's just how it is: a trust anchor may not be part of the certification path.  I don't see any problem in a library permitting that (and just ignoring the trust anchor cert if it's part of the certification path), but it appears that the APIs you're using don't permit that.  I don't think there's anything particularly deep going on; just some desire to keep APIs coherent with themselves and with the standards.